# Insert into new column the student_id and teacher_id

Tags: php, mysql

I have student table

```
|user_id|lastname|firtstname|
```

And teacher table

```
|teacher_id|lastname|firstname
```

I want to have a one login form that if the teacher_id is inputted the teacher will redirect to teacher.php and if the user_id is inputted it will redirect to user.php

or is there a way to get the user_id and teacher_id and insert to users
like this, the content of status is teacher or user

```
|users|lastname|firstname|status|
```

Comment: better with a users table, and a person table, and a boolean column on the person table to say if they are a student or teacher

Comment: If you found an answer, mark it as answer for others.

Comment: what if i will not use the second option. I only have the student table and teacher table and a one log in form. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
   $this->model->check();
}
```

Model.php:

```
public function check(){
 $id=$_POST['user_id'];

 $this->db->select('user_id');
 $this->db->from('user');
 $q1= $this->db->get();

 $this->db->select('teacher_id');
 $this->db->from('teacher');
 $q2= $this->db->get();

 if($id==$q1){
   redirect('');//to user.php
 }else if($id==$q2){
   redirect('');//to teacher.php
 }
}
```

View:

```
<form action="controller.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name='user_id'>
<input type='submit' name='login'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The latter approach would be better, as it makes easier to make sure that there is no teacher and student with same ID.

Just add all users to the same table, rather than to two different tables.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer second approach.

Add field type in your table and stored user's type like 1:teacher, 2:student(it's useful than boolean field. if you want to add another user type like 3:principal 4:helper ....)

And after successful login check user type and redirect where you want.